# spark write: CSV data source does not support null data type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an error in my code.  The code is dumping some data into Redshift database.

After some investigation I found an easy way to reproduce it in spark console.

This is working fine:

```
scala> Seq("France", "Germany").toDF.agg(avg(lit(null))).write.csv("1.csv")
scala>
```

But if I replace **avg** with **max** I got an error "CSV data source does not support null data type."

```
scala> Seq("France", "Germany").toDF.agg(max(lit(null))).write.csv("2.csv")
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support null data type.
```

What's wrong with **max** ?

Comment: df.agg(max(lit(null).cast(DataTypes.StringType))).write.csv("2.csv")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct as AVG returns the DOUBLE datatype

```
Seq("France", "Germany").toDF.agg(avg(lit(null)).alias("col1")).printSchema
```

[image]

where as MAX returns the type as null

```
Seq("France", "Germany").toDF.agg(max(lit(null)).alias("col1")).printSchema
```

[image]

so while you are writing the dataframe having MAX its throwing the error, if you want to save the dataframe with the max explicitely convert it into another type

```
Seq("France", "Germany").toDF.agg(max(lit(null)).alias("col1").cast(DoubleType)).write.csv("path")
```